# use system config value to disable code from requirejs-config.js

Tags: magento2, module, requirejs, system-config

I would like to create a configuration setting in my module's `adminhtml/system.xml` to disable it's features.

I know how I can system config values to disable code in LayoutXML or PHP but is it possible to use it to disable code in `<Module_dir>/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js`.

I want to be able to enable JavaScript mixins for a particular store view, I can achieve it by creating a theme and moving my module's requirejs-config.js into the theme, but I would prefer to keep all my logic within the Module directory.

Comment: Did you find the solution?

Comment: no, in the end I used a requirejs-config.js file in the theme for the storeview I wanted to use the module's mixins for.